# Is PREFETCH an asynchronous operation?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache, memory-access

I often hear Prefetching as a technique for speeding up, for example, sequential memory access pattern.  The prefetch should occur sufficiently far ahead in time to mitigate the latency of memory access, for example in a loop traversing memory linearly.

According to the famous "What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory" paper by Ulrich Drepper, it is written:

> This prefetching would remove some
>   of the costs of accessing main memory since it happens
>   **asynchronously** with respect to the execution of the program

*(emphasis mine)*

I could not find references on Google or Wikipedia corroborating or proving this. Does anyone know where I can find if this is true?

The only reasoning I can think of is rhetorical: it must be asynchronous b/c otherwise prefetching offers no benefit to sequential access... unless the execution time of prefetching a cache line is less than bypassing prefetch and placing the same cache line from RAM directly into cache.

Answer (score 3):

If it is implemented in hardware, prefetching is typically done asynchronously.

It's also possible for a compiler to insert extra prefetch instructions into the code.  Thus, the initiation of the fetch is done synchronously, but then the memory access continues asynchronously.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_prefetching.